# Why am I getting warnings when I'm trying to install RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM on a new machine. I have done it before and then it went fine. But now I keep getting these errors:

```
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders/.rvm/scripts/base' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders/.rvm/scripts/version' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders/.rvm/scripts/selector' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders/.rvm/scripts/cd' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders.rvm/scripts/cli' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
      Could not source '/Users/anders/.rvm/scripts/override_gem' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
cat: /Users/anders/.rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
/Users/anders/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 133: __rvm_conditionally_add_bin_path:      
command not found
```

I followed the steps on https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ but it doesn't work.

I used:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

when installing, I'm not running as root nor using `sudo`.

I also added this to my .bash_profile file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I checked and the "complaining" files do exist, so I guess it's a permission thing. Any tips on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happen if you try this?:  bash <<( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-latest )

Comment: @Nerian: It starts downloading, but then I get this error:        bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>

Comment: I modified it slightly but I keep getting the same warnings: bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-latest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `rvm notes` and check the output. Ensure that OS dependencies are installed.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work now. I ran rvm notes as you said and saw that xcode from the Snow Leopard install dvd have bugs. I tried to install xcode from developer.apple.com whitout removing the old version, but then I got the same warnings. I then made a clean OS installation (probably overkill), skipped xcode from the installation dvd downloaded it from developer.apple.com (and git etc.) and now it works. Would probably be enough to uninstall the old xcode version before installing but anyway, thanks!